# XmlNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild stops foreach

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

I'm trying to delete every note with type"deletable", but after it has hit 1 deletable, the foreach stops. In this case, only passing test2.exe and test.exe.

This is what my XML file looks like:

```
<folder name="bin">
    <file name="test2.exe" type="undeletable">test</file>
    <file name="test.exe" type="deletable">test</file>
    <file name="test1.exe" type="deletable">test</file>
    <file name="kernel.sys" type="undeletable">test</file>
</folder>
```

And this the C#:

```
XmlNodeList fileNodeLIst = fileNode.SelectNodes("file");
foreach(XmlNode file in fileNodeLIst) {
    if (file.Attributes["type"].Value == "undeletable") {
        TerminalSystemAddMessage("Error: Unable to delete " + file.Attributes["name"].Value);
    } else if (file.Attributes["type"].Value == "deletable") {
        file.ParentNode.RemoveChild(file);
        TerminalSystemAddMessage("Deleted: " + file.Attributes["name"].Value);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? **Why is the foreach loop breaking and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Modifying your code so that I can actually run it, I find it works just fine. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: What I posted, does not run fine. It stops the foreach when an deletable has been passed.

Comment: I don't doubt that in your scenario it fails to run. You wouldn't have posted the question otherwise. But you didn't provide a code example that _anyone else_ can run unmodified. Without that, it's not clear at all what's wrong in your code. I copy/pasted without modification the code you posted, but of course had to add other code just to get anything to run at all. And when I did, the result worked fine. Please read **and understand** the link I provided so that you know what kind of code example is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "for" iteration statement instead of "foreach" iteration statement like lines below:

```
  XmlNodeList fileNodeLIst = fileNode.SelectNodes("file");
    for(int iNode = fileNodeList.Count - 1; iNode >= 0; iNode --)
      {
        XmlNode file = fileNodeLIst[iNode];
        if(file.Attributes["type"].Value == "undeletable"){
            TerminalSystemAddMessage("Error: Unable to delete " + file.Attributes["name"].Value);
        }else if(file.Attributes["type"].Value == "deletable"){
            file.ParentNode.RemoveChild(file);
            TerminalSystemAddMessage("Deleted: " + file.Attributes["name"].Value);
        }
      }
```

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface. The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, **but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.**
>   source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Comment: First, the collection returned by `SelectNodes()` is not the actual DOM collection. So the DOM collection can be modified in the `foreach` just fine. Second, please do not use "snippets" to post C# code. Just post the code.

Comment: Notice: traverse the node list from the last one to the first one.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, Thanks for your note. How come there's no c# snippet support on StackOverflow?

Comment: @TeunissenStefan, Please mark my answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: _"How come there's no c# snippet support on StackOverflow?"_ -- same reason there's no snippet support for other languages either: no one's implemented it, most likely because it's not really practical to do so. Web code is one thing -- you're guaranteed to be presenting in a browser context -- but arbitrary C#, Java, C++, Pascal, Python, Perl, Ada, etc. just cannot be handled comprehensively.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this approach to be cleaner:

```
var messages =
(
    from file in fileNode.SelectNodes("file").Cast<XmlNode>()
    let deletable = file.Attributes["type"].Value == "deletable"
    let name = file.Attributes["name"].Value
    select String.Format(
        deletable
            ? "Deleted: {0}"
            : "Error: Unable to delete {0}",
        name)
).ToList();

var deletables =
(
    from file in fileNode.SelectNodes("file").Cast<XmlNode>()
    where file.Attributes["type"].Value == "deletable"
    select file
).ToList();

deletables.ForEach(file => file.ParentNode.RemoveChild(file));
messages.ForEach(message => TerminalSystemAddMessage(message));
```

This separates the deleting of the node from the iterating through the list - so stops the problem you're experiencing.